# Any libraries for a query-caching-type functionality for sets/dicts?

Tags: python, data-structures, set

For a project I'm currently working on I've noticed that many of the set lookups I'm doing come clustered, so even though my set contain 100k+ elements, lookups are highly predictable, so that if I now lookup X, my next lookup will be X with 90%+ probability.
It seems that I can improve my lookup speed by adding a thin cache on top of my set which remembers, say, the last 10 looked up items. Before I implement something like this myself, are there any existing libraries for doing this? Any advice?

Comment: Python 3 has [`functools.lru_cache`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache).

Comment: @MartijnPieters do you think it would make sense to use it for caching a set or dict lookup? I have a feeling that it would only make it slower...

Comment: @LevLevitsky: Indeed; set and dict lookups are *already* fast, not sure how a cache would help there. But this post is too thin on details, and a resource recommendation request to boot.